# How to debug Microservice in cumulocity platform

Tags: iot, cumulocity

I wrote microservices using spring boot. some time showing its active in status and sometimes showing inactive, I can't understand the behaviour of microservice and how can debug it

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested running the microservice locally?

I've been getting inconsistent reports from the status tab in the UI. Sometimes it says the service is down when it's actually up. I check the /health endpoint to be sure(it's not available right after you upload the zip, takes 5-6 minutes).

The logs in the UI are a bit clunky, so I've added a rolling file appender to logback.xml and a rest endpoint to expose the log file for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Try to override health check timeout value (timeoutSeconds property of Probe). By default it's 1 second and it's often not enough. Please refer our specification: https://cumulocity.com/guides/reference/microservice-manifest/

Answer (score 0):

In the administration application you will find the status details for each of your applications.
When the status is switching all the time probably the docker container is terminating all the time (probably because the application is crashing). You should the that on the status tab of the application in the event log (container is restarted all the time).

If you are on the newest Cumulocity version (9.19.x) you should also have access to the logs of the microservice at the same place in UI. You need to log to stdout in order to be able to get the logs through administration application.

Comment: I try with 9.19.0 but still not working and not getting any log

Comment: I found the issue in Cumulocity, not supporting spring 2+ if you using spring 1.5.X then it's working properly